# $.inArray() for Elements Stored in Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose in jQuery I push DOM elements into an array,

```
var elemarray = [];

elemarray.push($('#elem1'));
elemarray.push($('#elem2'));
```

Would it be possible to then use `$.inArray` to determine if the array contains an element?

```
if ( $.inArray($('#elem2'), elemarray) > -1 ) { .. }
```

The only examples I saw for primitive types, strings and numbers.

JSFiddle, not working: https://jsfiddle.net/5knyrcph/2/

Comment: You should really use  `!== -1`

Comment: No, it would not. Each call to `$()` returns a distinct new jQuery object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5knyrcph/3/ - working fiddle. You have to get the text of the div before comparing. I also utilized `!== -1`

Comment: So you found a way to stringify a field, in this case based on its content. I see

Comment: Yes for the most part... you have to get the DIV text otherwise it is just an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are not storing DOM elements, but jQuery wrappers. Every time you create such a wrapper, it is a new jQuery object.

Instead use the real DOM elements themselves, which with jQuery you can get with `.get()`:

```js
var elemarray = [];
elemarray.push($('#elem1').get(0));
elemarray.push($('#elem2').get(0));

if ($.inArray($('#elem1').get(0), elemarray) > -1) {
  console.log('Found');
}
else {
  console.log('Not found');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="elem1">
Test
</div>

<div id="elem2">
Test2
</div>
```

In HTML5 / ES6 you can do this without jQuery in shorter code:

```js
const elemSet = new Set([elem1, elem2]);

if (elemSet.has(elem1)) {
  console.log('Found');
}
else {
  console.log('Not found');
}
```

```html
<div id="elem1">
Test
</div>

<div id="elem2">
Test2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should use `!== -1`

And here is the fiddle to the corrected JS: https://jsfiddle.net/5knyrcph/3/

Code:

```
var elemarray = [];

elemarray.push($('#elem1').text());
elemarray.push($('#elem2').text());
alert(elemarray[0]);

if ($.inArray($('#elem1').text(), elemarray) !== -1) {
  alert('Found');
}
else {
  alert('Not found');
}
```

Comment: In other words serialization/stringification of some kind. Thanks for the tip

Comment: `div` is an element, and `.text()` gives you the text inside the div which you are inserting into the array to compare.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this solved your question.

Comment: There is no problem in comparing like OP did: `> -1` is fine. Secondly, if an element is looked for in the array, that happens to have the same text, but is a different DOM element, this will say "Found", while it is not really the same DOM element.

Comment: While it is true, i gave him a easier solution but getting with `.get` also works in this case, sure.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery return an Array of items that match the criteria, so when ever you select an element it always will construct a brand new array of objects that match your criteria, in order to compare the elements you need to either get the element inside the array with these two options:

```
$(".element")[position]; //or
$(".element").get(position);
```

If in your fiddle instead of pushing the Jquery object, you push the actual element, then you'll get your results right.
[Fiddle Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/21gwn852/2/)

Hope this help